# How does ChatGPT render math in Markdown output?

Tags: chatgpt

ChatGPT renders inline math output like this:

Markdown: `is \( 2^4 = 16 \).`

Rendered:

[image]

It doesn't use the typical `$ ... $` or `$$ ... $$` to wrap around math expressions (like in LaTex / MathJax), so what exactly does it use to render math in markdown?

What's the notation of `\( ... \)`?

I'd like to preview (preferrably using VS Code)
and render (to pdf, using pandoc) the copied answer markdown with math correctly,
and knowing how the ChatGPT web UI does it would help me do that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `\( ... \)` syntax corresponds to LaTex math inline mode.

Regarding printing as PDF-rendered versions of markdown files, including Tex, LaTex, and MatJax, there are a lot of plug-ins for Visual Studio Code. Search the [Visual Studio Marketplace](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/) or the Web. There is a lot of content.

As an alternate to Visual Studio Code, check out Obsidian.md. This is a note application that use markdown and also has a lot of plug-ins.

Reference

- [Are ( and ) preferable to dollar signs for math mode?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/510)

---

Related

- [Syvshc's answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/582870) to [LaTeX Convention for displaymath](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/582868)
- [New feature: Properly shown mathematical equations](https://community.openai.com/t/new-feature-properly-shown-mathematical-equations/73833/2)

Comment: Thanks for answering! Do you happen to know how I can produce PDF from a markdown file with LaTex inline math?

Comment: @TeddyC Take a look to Obsidian.md. I have started using it later, it has several community developed plugins. If the feature that you are looking for is not built-in, it's very likely that there should be a plug-in for what you are looking for.

Comment: @TeddyC I updated my answer. I didn't add anything specific. If you need a specific recommendation, consider posting a question on [softwarerecs.se], as it's very likely that they are better prepared to handle software recommendation questions.

Answer (score 2):

> It doesn't use the typical `$ ... $` or `$$ ... $$` to wrap around math expressions (like in LaTex / MathJax), so what exactly does it use to render math in markdown?

It does use the typical `$ ... $` or `$$ ... $$` to wrap around math expressions if within a latex document, see the [example](https://chat.openai.com/share/bc91db77-fa0a-4fe2-ba13-9859dd4ebd31) below:

[image]

Prompt:

> Generate a latex document with a math equation

Raw output:

````
Sure, here's an example of a LaTeX document with a simple math equation:

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}  % Required for math equations

\title{Math Equation Example}
\author{Your Name}
\date{\today}

\begin{document}

\maketitle

This is an example of a math equation:

\begin{equation}
    f(x) = ax^2 + bx + c
\end{equation}

Where $a$, $b$, and $c$ are constants, and $x$ is the variable.

\end{document}
\```

Copy and paste this code into a `.tex` file and compile it using a LaTeX compiler to generate a PDF document. The equation in this example is a quadratic equation, and the `amsmath` package is used to provide enhanced support for mathematical notation and formatting.
````

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I noticed that it does use `$ $` most of the times, but it seems that in Code Interpreter mode it tends to use `\( \)` more.